# Can't Cross Compile GDBServer for MIPS n32

Tags: linux, gdb, mips, cross-compiling, gdbserver

I'm having trouble cross compiling GDBServer for MIPS n32.  I'm using GCC-4.7.2, binutils-2.22, glibc-2.11.1, glibc-ports-2.11, and linux-2.6.32.61.  My host is x86_64-cross-linux-gnu.  My target is mips64-elf-linux.  The specific ABI for MIPS is [n32](http://techpubs.sgi.com/library/manuals/2000/007-2816-005/pdf/007-2816-005.pdf).

When I go to make GDBserver, I get an error while compiling regcache.c.  regcache.c is in the gdb/gdbserver/.  There is a struct called 'reg' that gcc is trying to compile.  I have included all of the mips include files.  I can compile GDBServer for x86 however.  I greped all of the include files in /usr/include/ to try to find "struct reg" and was unsuccessful on finding anything.  I found this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201194/differnce-between-struct-reg-and-struct-user-regs-struc) and I changed the names hoping that it would correct the issue but that won't work because the reg struct in regcache.c has attributes like offset and value.  I have also tried messing with pt_regs in ptrace.h.  However I don't think I should have to mess with the files that come with GDBServer.

My configure command is:

```
CC=mips64-elf-linux-gcc configure --host=x86_64-cross-linux-gnu --target=mips64-elf-linux
```

Does anyone know why I can't comiple GDBServer for Mips n32?

Thanks,

UPDATE:

```
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:207:7: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct reg'
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:207:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:208:7: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct reg'
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:208:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c: In function 'find+_register_by_name'
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:295:7: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct reg'
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:295:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c: In function 'find_regno'
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:315:7: error: invalid use of undefined type 'struct reg'
../gdb-7.6/gdb/gdbserver/regcache.c:315:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
```

Comment: Please update with the exact error message that you are getting when you compile.